# How to insert a row to a field of type Array in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

Have a table with the following schema:

```
   Name <STRING> 
   Marks <ARRAY>
   Rank <INT>
```

I need to add a row using INSERT INTO, but am unable to add for type ARRAY. Could anyone please help here.